# Link weight between DBpedia objects

Tags: algorithm, semantic-web, dbpedia

I am bit new to this semantic web topic and especially **DBpedia**, as much as I did reading about this I could not find any information about possibility to determine weight of link between DBpedia objects. For example, **is it possible to determine that PHP is more related to Symfony than Ruby on Rails** is, even though they are both related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OWLIM has an algorithm called RDF Rank which is mentioned in this [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/ontotext/owlim-basics-and-new-features) but it doesn't say how it works, I couldn't find any articles/papers with a quick Google search but probably worth you looking more thoroughly.

If all you want to know is how linked some concepts are it may be easiest to set up OWLIM yourself and import the DBPedia dataset dump and run the algorithm so you can retrieve this information.